# PHPunit Code Coverage error

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, pear

PHPunit is working, but I get this code coverage error and don't get the code coverage report.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,

Demian.

```
demian@dimbo-TP:/var/www/z2d2/tests$ phpunit
PHPUnit 3.5.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.

...

Time: 1 second, Memory: 13.00Mb

OK (3 tests, 4 assertions)

Generating code coverage report, this may take a moment.PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHP_Token_Stream' not found in /usr/share/php/PHP/Token/Stream/CachingFactory.php on line 68
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:49
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:188
PHP   5. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML->process() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:363
PHP   6. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML->addItems() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML.php:135
PHP   7. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML_Node_Directory->addFile() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML.php:214
PHP   8. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML_Node_File->__construct() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML/Node/Directory.php:156
PHP   9. PHP_CodeCoverage_Util::getLinesToBeIgnored() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML/Node/File.php:169
PHP  10. PHP_Token_Stream_CachingFactory::get() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Util.php:271

Fatal error: Class 'PHP_Token_Stream' not found in /usr/share/php/PHP/Token/Stream/CachingFactory.php on line 68

Call Stack:
    0.0002     326940   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0434     666604   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:49
    0.0435     667084   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
    0.0943    4312004   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:188
    1.1150   13272196   5. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML->process() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:363
    1.1521   14100768   6. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML->addItems() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML.php:135
    1.1521   14101320   7. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML_Node_Directory->addFile() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML.php:214
    1.1521   14103132   8. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML_Node_File->__construct() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML/Node/Directory.php:156
    1.1595   14122724   9. PHP_CodeCoverage_Util::getLinesToBeIgnored() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML/Node/File.php:169
    1.1595   14123076  10. PHP_Token_Stream_CachingFactory::get() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Util.php:271
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are running PHPUnit 3.5.x so the Token stream version you need can be installed using:

```
sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage-1.0.2
```

If you want to update to the current version of phpunit something alone the lines of

```
sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/phpunit
```

will do the job but if i remember correctly you are trying to use the Zend Framework testing environment and that only works with PHPUnit 3.5.15

---

If both options fail or are not suitable go for

```
sudo pear install --force phpunit/PHP_TokenStream
```

---

### What will definitely get you a working PHPUnit 3.5.15

http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/

**Important note**: if you install PHPUnit via PEAR. This installation method is no longer
supported and http://pear.phpunit.de/ will be shut down no later than
December, 31 2014.

Please read http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html and
learn how to use PHPUnit from a PHAR or install it via Composer.

Comment: Hi,I have tried both these methods and the problem persists. However, I think you are close because if I go to /usr/share/php/PHP/Token.php and look inside, it is version 1.1.1. The same goes for /usr/share/php/PHP/Token/Stream.php - also 1.1.1 How can I get version 1.0.2?

Comment: @dimbo Try `pear install --force phpunit/PHP_TokenStream-1.0.1`

Comment: sudo pear install --force phpunit/PHP_TokenStream-1.0.1 That was the line that fixed it for me. Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 2):

If all efforts to downgrade phpunit 3.6 to 3.5 not success.
You can fix this problem by add bellow code to /usr/share/php/PHP/Token/Stream/CachingFactory.php to fix "Class 'PHP_Token_Stream' not found..."

```
require_once('PHP/Token/Stream/Autoload.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix phpunit by re-installing:

```
$ pear upgrade -f phpunit
```

Comment: Hi, I have actually downgraded because I need to use PHPunit with zend framework. Perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: A re-install can still be helpful after a downgrade; I ran into this issue, and my final solution was to remove phpunit with composer (just by taking it out and running update), and then add back in the version I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Installing phpunit with pear did not work for me at all.

What I finally did is (in some directory for example **/home/USERNAME/phpunit**):

```
wget http://pear.phpunit.de/get/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
```

And in .bash.rc add the end

```
export PATH=${PATH}:PATH_WHERE_YOU_PUT_phpunit.phar
```

In my example PATH_WHERE_YOU_PUT_phpunit.phar will be /home/USERNAME/phpunit

After that, phpunit be can executed  with command **phpunit.phar** in whatever directory

Answer (score 0):

An option for some linux distros might be to use yum or apt-get to install phpunit.

I am using Fedora 17 and installed phpunit with yum, everything worked fine at first try. Not sure how well Ubuntu/Mint packages work.

In Windows I used pear and it worked fine there but since I found phpunit in yum I thought I'd give that a try first.